# Specify Priority on Div

Tags: css

I have a

```
<div class="banner-right">
```

and a

```
<div class="logo">
```

The Div Class Logo overlaps the banner-right, but the problem is that the right banner covers the logo. Is there a way to set the logo to say that it's more important and it will show over the banner?

```
div.logo
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 483px;
    margin-left: 472px;
    width: 214px;
    height: 169px;
    background-image:url(images/doxramos_logo.png);
        }

div.head-banner-right
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 159px;
    margin-left: 472px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    background-image:url(images/metal_grid.jpg)
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `z-index` css property which will cause elements styled with a higher `z-index` to appear above those with a lower `z-index`.  This only works for absolutely and relatively positioned elements.  Since your elements have `position: absolute` you should be able to just add the `z-index` property to your css styles for each element.

```
   div.logo
    {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 11px;
        left: 483px;
        margin-left: 472px;
        width: 214px;
        height: 169px;
        background-image:url(images/doxramos_logo.png);
        z-index: 100;
    }

    div.head-banner-right
    {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 159px;
        margin-left: 472px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 60px;
        background-image:url(images/metal_grid.jpg)
        z-index: 50;
      }
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HTM5v/

MDN Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.

Comment: Awesome; I had tried that earlier to no avail and used 1 and 2 as my z indexes; is it a requirement that they be in increments of 50?

Comment: No, I just arbitrarily picked those numbers.  Are you sure you elements were absolutely positioned when you tried to use z-index prior?

Comment: I think I had them set to relative; but I'm doubting myself now. Either way; Thanks for the answer and the little bit of knowledge to add. :)